# Regular expression to accept 4 chars with different pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying for a regular expression for below requirement.

1. Total string length must be 3 or 4.
2. First two characters must be from a-z or A-Z
3. Last two characters must be from 0-9

I have tried the below, but I know this is not the good way

```
     var str = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,2} + [0-9]{2} + $/,
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: from your question; First two characters and Last two characters = 4 characters; therefore the total string length will always be 4.

Comment: @joberror From his regex, the first two characters are optional (can be one or two)

Comment: Do you want to match `+` as well or why are they there?

Comment: @NiftyDude; Okay I can see clearly.

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually, those `+` wouldn't match literal plus signs :)

Comment: Your rules are contradictory. If the first two characters must be letters and the last two characters must be digits, there can never be a string of length 3.

Comment: @Tim: Oh... right :D Note to self (again): Never comment on questions when you just woke up :D Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = /^([a-z]{1,2}|[A-Z]{1,2})[0-9]{2}$/;
```

Then you test it as:

```
str.test("aa3"); // false, 2 integers are required
str.test("a34"); // true
str.test("aA33"); // false, 2 first characters have to be in the same case
```

Not sure what you really mean by `First two characters must be from a-z or A-Z`, if you want those characters to be the same cases, use the regex above, otherwise

```
var str = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2}$/;
```

Comment: Where does it say in the requirements that both characters have to be in the same case?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Someone actually pointed that out (he deleted his comment), but I take it from `First two characters must be from a-z or A-Z`, do you think I interpret it wrong?

Comment: I have no idea, the whole spec is very hazy.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Right :S, I'll just edit my answer to include both cases then :s, thanks sir professor!